# Counting number of times A part of String is present is the DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with below data-points. Here `count` represents number of times articleTag is read. `articleTag` is the `tag` for articleId; i.e. for articleId `590020` there are four tags `A,B,C,D` which is represented as one string.

```
      articleId     articleTag       count  
  0     590020      A,B,C,D             2   
  1     466322      A,B,E               3   
  2     466322      B                   2   
  3     466322      A                   1
```

I need to find out `tag distribution` i.e. for each tag how many number of times it appeared in articles and how many number of times its read.

like in above sample Dataframe.

```
Tag       Present       Read
A           3            6
B           3            7
C           1            2
D           1            2
E           1           3
```

Pl help.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([{"articleId": 590020, "articleTag": "A,B,C,D ", "count": 6}, {"articleId": 590021, "articleTag": "A,B,E", "count": 3}])

In [3]: df[df.articleTag.str.contains("A")]['count'].sum()
Out: 9

In [4]: len(df[df.articleTag.str.contains("A")])
Out[4]: 2
```

The first is your "Read" value and the second is your "Present" value.

To find all the various tags, I'd probably do something like this:

```
In [5]: tag_df = df.articleTag.str.split(',', expand=True)

In [6]: for column in tag_df.columns:
...:     print(tag_df[column].unique())
...:     
...:     
['A']
['B']
['C' 'E']
['D ' None]
```

Instead of printing them you can add them to a `set` and collect all the tags you need to look for that way.

```
In [7]: unique_tags = set()

In [8]: for column in tag_df.columns:
    ...:     unique_tags |= set(tag_df[column].unique())
    ...:     
    ...:     
    ...:     
    ...:     

In [9]: unique_tags
Out[9]: {'B', 'A', 'C', 'E', None, 'D '}
```

Of course you'll have to pull out the None vals.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"articleId": 590020, "articleTag": "A,B,C,D ", "count": 2}, 
                   {"articleId": 590021, "articleTag": "A,B,E", "count": 3},
                  {"articleId": 466322, "articleTag": "B", "count": 2},
                   {"articleId": 466322, "articleTag": "A", "count": 1}])
articles = []
for val in df['articleTag'].values:
    articles.extend(val.split(','))
unique_articles = list(set(articles))

final_dict = {}
final_dict['article'] = unique_articles
final_count = []
final_read = []
for article in unique_articles:
        l = [val for val in df['articleTag'].values if article in val]
        l2 = [val[1] for val in zip(df['articleTag'].values,df['count'].values) if article in val[0]]
        final_read.append(sum(l2))
        final_count.append(len(l))
final_dict['Present'] = final_count
final_dict['Read'] = final_read
pd.DataFrame(final_dict)
```

Comment: With the above code a part of string is also being considered . for example if tag is `naren`  whose read count to be calculated  . So if its tested  against   `narendra modi,bjp` then its count is incremented.  But I don't want  this. The tag has to be present  as whole.

Comment: use == instead of 'in'